# My C++ code not showing floating point value

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

My code is not showing exact float value means number after point is not displayed by the code
I am using Turbo C for sum up the series 1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/9+….. Up to N terms

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int k=0;
    int m=0;
    int s=1;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter the limit of the series: ";
    cin>>m;
    for(int j=1;j<=m;j=j+2)
    {
          m=1/j;
          s+=m;
    }
    cout<<"Sum of the given series is: "<<s;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `int` as in **integer**. Use `double` instead.

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: Any time you ask a question, you should clearly state (**1**)what input you gave your program, (**2**)what output you expected, and (**3**)what output you actually got.  This question failed on all three points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `int` which only displays *Integer* (ie whole number) values. It truncates any decimal places because it assumes you don't want them. Try using `float` or `double` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division will not give you anything other than integer results.

You need to:

1. Change `s` to a float or double.
2. change `m` to a float or double.
3. Change `1` in `1/j` to `1.0f` or `1.0` (for float and double respectively).

Now, you probably also want to use a different variable than `m` for your input and for-loop limit variable, so that you don't stop too quickly once the calculation starts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the type `double` for variables `m` and `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the variables you declared in your code.

```
int k=0;
int m=0;
int s=1;
```

Where exactly do you think you have a floating point number?
*(which would have to be of type `float` or `double`)*

You do know that `int` means **integer**, right? 
*(eg. Not a floating point number)*